# How to solve Null Pointer Exception in Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, nullpointerexception

I am new one for play framework.

I am working with two form, that is in first form i give the two values and pass this value to next form, in this next form i want to add this two number. But i got null pointer excpetion in te following line

```
addition data=addform.get();

        return ok(
                sum_resul.render(data.First_No,data.Second_No)           //(sum was given form name)
                );
        }
```

How can i solve this problem.

Here My code

**route**

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()


GET    /Sum_result                  controllers.Application.sumresult()


GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

**Application.java**

```
package controllers;

 import play.mvc.*;
 import play.data.*;                                    
 import static play.data.Form.*;    
 import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;         
 import views.html.*;

 public class Application extends Controller {

public static class addition
{

    @Required @Min(1) @Max(100) 
    public Integer First_No;  

    @Required @Min(1) @Max(100) 
    public Integer Second_No;

}

public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render(Form.form(addition.class)));
}


public static Result sumresult()
{

Form<addition> addform=form(addition.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(addform.hasErrors())
    {
        return badRequest(index.render(addform));
    }
    else
    {
        addition data=addform.get();

        return ok(
                sum_resul.render(data.First_No,data.Second_No)           
                );
        }


}



}
```

**index.scala**

```
@(additionForm: Form[Application.addition])  

@import helper._

@main(title="The 'addition' Program") {

<h1>Configure Your 'Numbers'</h1>

@form(action=routes.Application.sumresult,args='id ->"additionForm"){           
@inputText(
field=additionForm("First_No"),
args='_label -> "Enter First Number",'placeholder -> "0-100"
)

@inputText(
field=additionForm("Second_No"),
args='_label -> "Enter Second Number",'placeholder -> "0-100"
)

 <p class="buttons">
        <input type="submit">
    <p>


    }
}
```

**sum_resul.scala**

```
@(First_No: Int, Second_No: Int)

@main("Here is the result:") {

<h1>
Sum of @First_No and @Second_No was (First_No+Second_No)
</h1>

<p class="buttons">
    <a href="@routes.Application.index">Back to the form</a>
</p>
}
```

**Exception like**

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems fairly self explanatory, `data` is null and you are trying to retrieve values from it. So, you need to track down why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.size>0)  
  return ok(
                sum_resul.render(data.First_No,data.Second_No)           //(sum was given form name)
                );
```